# How can I add two different data types char and int in c language?

Tags: c

This is the code; and in this one a + c gives me result in digit, why? The output below. How the character is converted into a digit? And why 125 + 'c' = 212? Thank you in response!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a = 125, b = 12345;
    long ax = 1234567890;
    short s = 4043;
    float x = 2.13459;
    double dx = 1.1415927;
    char c = 'W';
    unsigned long ux = 2541567890;
    printf("a + c =  %d\n", a + c);
    printf("x + c = %f\n", x + c);
    printf("dx + x = %f\n", dx + x);
    printf("((int) dx) + ax =  %ld\n", ((int) dx) + ax);
    printf("a + x = %f\n", a + x);
    printf("s + b =  %d\n", s + b);
    printf("ax + b = %ld\n", ax + b);
    printf("s + c =  %hd\n", s + c);
    printf("ax + c = %ld\n", ax + c);
    printf("ax + ux = %lu\n", ax + ux);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
a + c =  212                                                           
x + c = 89.134590                                                      
dx + x = 3.276183                                                      
((int) dx) + ax =  1234567891                                          
a + x = 127.134590                                                     
s + b =  16388                                                         
ax + b = 1234580235                                                    
s + c =  4130                                                          
ax + c = 1234567977                                                    
ax + ux = 3776135780
```

Comment: Please note that `char` is an integer type (and `'W'` is of type `int` not `char`). A character isn't *converted* to a "digit", it is the human representation on a screen or a printer of what the value means in that context. So for example in the ASCII coding system, the **W** you see here is represented by the numeric value `87` and the **W** shape only exists on your retina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the code; and in this one a + c gives me result in digit, why?

It gives you this output, as you 1) specified, that you want to print an integer (`%d`) and 2) If you add a char to an int, the result is an int.

> How the character is converted into a digit?

Each character has an int value, ('A'=65,' '=32,...,See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

> And why 125 + 'c' = 212?

'c' has the ASCII-Value 87, and 125+87==212.